# My sed command to insert lines into a file is not working - is special characters the issue?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to add a couple of lines in a text file with sed.

I think I have special characters that are giving me the issue.

I want to insert lines between

```
username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
```

and

```
kind: ConfigMap
```

This is what I want to insert -

```
    - groups:
      - eks-role
      - system:master
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/eks
      username: eks
  mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user/test-ecr
    username: test-ecr
    groups:
    - eks-role
```

I have also tried using forward slashes around the special characters to no avail.

Here is the sed command I have now that does not work - it seems not to insert anything. I assume it can't find the line "username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}".

```
sed '/^username\: system:node\:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}$/r'<(
echo "    - groups:"
echo "      - eks-role"
echo "      - system:master"
echo "      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/eks"
echo "      username: eks"
echo "  mapUsers: |"
echo "    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user/test-ecr"
echo "    username: ecr"
echo "    groups:"
echo "    - eks-role"
) -i -- temp-aws-auth.yaml
```

Here is the contents of the file that I want to insert into -

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/eksctl-ops-nodegroup-linux-ng-sys-NodeInstanceRole-763ALQD2ZGXK
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-12-09T15:54:56Z"
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "1298"
```

Comment: please update the question with the actual line you're trying to insert (as opposed to us trying to pull from the `sed` command); alternatively, provide the expected output

Comment: Don't treat a YAML file as text to be edited; treat it as a data structure to be parsed, updated, and reserialized.

Comment: In my circumstance I need to treat it as a text to be edited. I updated the post and added what I need inserted.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: Taking into consideration OPs answer/comment re: missing spaces, and a bit more fiddling, I was able to get the following `sed` command to work, too:

```
sed '/^.*username.*EC2PrivateDNSName.*$/r'<(cat replace.txt) temp-aws-auth.yaml
```

---

Assumptions:

- OP is unable to use a yaml-aware tool to perform the edit
- `username ... EC2PrivateDNSName` only shows up in one place in the file (or, alternatively, it shows up in multiple places and OP wishes to add a new line after each occurrence)

Replacement data:

```
$ cat replace.txt
    - groups:
      - eks-role
      - system:master
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/eks
      username: eks
  mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user/test-ecr
    username: test-ecr
    groups:
    - eks-role
```

**NOTE**: If the replacement data is in a variable it can fed into `awk` as a herestring.

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==NR                       { a[FNR]=$0        # store first file (replacement data) into an array
                                next }           # skip to next line in first file
                              { print }          # print current line of second file
/username.*EC2PrivateDNSName/ { for (i in a)     # if we found our match then dump the contents of array a[] to stdout
                                    print a[i]
                                next
                              }
' replace.txt temp-aws-auth.yaml
```

Or as a single-line:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[FNR]=$0; next} {print} /username.*EC2PrivateDNSName/ { for (i in a) print a[i]; next}' replace.txt temp-aws-auth.yaml
```

This generates:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/eksctl-ops-nodegroup-linux-ng-sys-NodeInstanceRole-763ALQD2ZGXK
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
    - groups:
      - eks-role
      - system:master
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/eks
      username: eks
  mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user/test-ecr
    username: test-ecr
    groups:
    - eks-role
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-12-09T15:54:56Z"
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "1298"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out the issue with my original command - Sed needs the spaces included in the line it is looking for!

Since the line I was looking for has spaces in it :

```
'      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}'
```

I had to add the spaces to my sed statement :

```
sed '/^      username\: system:node\:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}$/r'<(
```

Thanks for the feedback!
Happy holidays!!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & cat):

```
cat <<\! |sed  ':a;/username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}/{n;/kind: ConfigMap/!ba;h;s/.*/cat -/ep;g}' file
  - groups:
    - eks-role
    - system:master
    rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/eks
    username: eks
mapUsers: |
  - userarn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:user/test-ecr
  username: test-ecr
  groups:
  - eks-role
!
```

Make a here-document with the lines to be inserted.

Pipe the here-document through to a sed command.

If a line contains `username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}`, print it and fetch the next line.

If the following line does not contain `kind: ConfigMap` go to the start of the sed cycle and start again.

Otherwise, copy the current line, replace/print the current line by the lines to inserted from the here-document and then over write the replacement by the copy in the hold space.

N.B. The replacement lines are inserted into the document by way of the substitute command and the `e` flag, that evaluates what is substituted into the pattern space i.e. the `cat -` that is the here-document that is passed through via the pipe.